# Finding Points on a curve, that have a specific distance

Tags: functions, trigonometry, vectors, elliptic-functions

If you have any function or curve, and a point $(x_0|y_0)$, what formula do you use to determine a point with a specific distance D, on that curve.

Let's say, given an ellipse, you need to determine a function $\theta(t)$, for which $y=a \times sin(\theta(t))$ and $x=b \times cos(\theta(t))$ have a distance D to $v=a \times sin(\theta(t+1))$  and $w=b \times cos(\theta(t+1))$
Meaning, that $\sqrt{(y-v)^2+(x-w)^2}=D$

additionally, I would like to ask, if there is a general formula to solve this for any function? (formula/ way/ algorithm)

Comment: You have written down your implicit equation already. It may not be possible to write $\theta (t)=$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say our Point, *P*, has the co-ordinates, ($x_0 , y_0$), and our curve is f(x,y)=0, and we want a Distance *D*, from the said point.

Lets say a point *q*, that satisfies this, has co-ordinates ($x_1,y_1$). As you stated, this would satisfy $f(x_1,y_1)=0$.

For functions of the form $y = f(x)$, we can see that $y_1 = f(x_1)$.

Indeed, we would also want $\sqrt{(x_0-x_1)^2+(y_0-y_1)^2} = D$.

As $y_1 = f(x_1)$, we can substitute this into the above equation, and solve for $x_1$, and the using $y_1 = f(x_1)$, we can obtain $y_1$, and the point, *q*.

For more complex functions, it can still be possible (for example one can do it with all [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section), by using the same method.

For other complex functions, I am not sure how it can be done analytically. We can of course apply numerical methods, such as [Newton Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and [Staicase and Cobweb plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i made this whole post because I wanted to do an animate fourier series plot (of a logo of the band of a friend of mine), for the logo, only straight lines and ellipses were used, so i took the lines and made points with unit distance to each other to plot the logo in a spreadsheet. However I was unable to get unit distance for the points on the ellipses. Therefore I asked this question and whether there was and actual way of solving this problem, that I didn't know of yet and specifically how to solve for theta(t). (i had theta(t)=c*t, where c is a constant, but this obviously doesn't work).

Comment: so i would really like to see any approximation to the ellipse problem that is better than theta(t)=c*t. (the better the approximation, the more you can consider me being thankful to you)